# Import data into openproject database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, openproject

I can have a look at already existing data in the table but when i choose a file and submit import action i get the following error

> (Unknown action)
>   The action 'import' could not be found for TypesController

My index.html.erb

```
<h1>Import</h1>
<p>Monthly Report</p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @types.each do |type| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%=type.name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>
  <h2>Import the data!</h2>
  <%= form_tag import_types_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My routes.rb

```
OpenProject::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :types do
    collection { post :import }
  end

  root to: "types#index"
end
```

My types_controller.rb

```
class TypesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @types=Type.all
  end

  def import
    Type.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to_root_url, notice: "Activity data imported!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you even have that action? can you please post routes.rb, TypesController.rb and result of `rake routes` if possible

Comment: Im not sure is it help but try to add method: :put to form definition. I suppose that without it you send form via GET

Comment: It did not work can you please suggest me someother way